# iOS app localisation, how to organise localisable data?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I have an app, like quizzes and a have a bunch of questions in it that I would like to localise.
UI and resources are easy to get done, but what about data?

I have one solution in mind, like add additional flag to model, smth like `'locale'` (for example `{locale: "eng"}` and then just filter data from storage according to user settings, but I wonder is there is another way. Couldn't find any so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is better way then this one. You have to add strings files in your project for each language you want to show in your app. You can refer [a Internationalisation Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)!

Comment: if I understood it correct, that article is just about  localising UI or string in the code, which is essentials.

My question is different, imagine you have a collection (in db or whatever) with pack of strings. And your code has to pull this strings from db and show localised version to a user.

Comment: Ok, so for your requirement you can filter from your db or other datasource directly to target language which reduce your data load( or processing) also, and bind it to you modal directly or display it directly.

Comment: yeah, but the problem with this approach is straightforward - how to manage translations. With strings its easy - export to XLIFF and reimport, but with data in DB its becoming cumbersome